# Eliminating repetition among the dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working on creating a dictionary in python but the thin line between list and python is confusing me alot. What i have is

`values = []`

where in i'll store the values as

`values.append({newvalue : oldvalue})`

the list or dictionary whatever it is, it's working but is not checking for repetition among itself. so what i did is

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    if ((newvalue not in values[i])):
         values.append({newvalue: oldvalue})
```

but this is not working. why? and how can i resolve this? and if you have time please explain how different is list with dictionary and what do i have in my code. a list or a dictionary?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You are building a list of dictionaries, each with a single key and value. Did you want to build a dictionary instead?

Comment: If so, do `values = {}`, then `values[newvalue] = oldvalue`.

Comment: That is the problem i'm finding it hard to understand the difference among dictionary and list...any help?

Comment: One is an ordered list of items, the other maps unique keys to values, and is unordered. You want to read the [Python tutorial on data structures](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, if you want an empty dictionary, dont do `values = []` that will make a list, instead do

```
values = {}
```

when adding to a dictionary, do this

```
mydict[mykey] = myvalue
```

when checking to see if something is already in the keys do this

```
if newkey not in mydict:
    print('this will not overwrite anything')
```

I think you are misunderstanding the concept of a dictionary
When you do this `key` will be your dictionary key, and `val` will be your dictionary value.  A dictionary is a combination of pairs of terms in the order {key: value} so if you do `myDict[key]` you will get `value`

---

If you want to add to a dictionary while making sure that you aren't overwriting anything, this simple example will do that for you.

```
if newkey not in mydict:
    mydict[newkey] = newvalue
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try this @stephan but can you answer my complete question i'm new to real world python programming so kinda find it hard to draw a line between list and dictionary

Comment: @NottyShinchan sure i'll add it in a moment

Comment: You don't need `.keys ()` here... also, you're better off creating the new dict, then `update`ing from the old (the way I'm reading your example anyway)

Comment: @JonClements didn't know you could shortcut that thanks

Comment: Excellent @Stephan...thanks for the shortcut!

Comment: @stephan in python 2.x - .keys returns a list, which means a linear search... in 3.x, it returns a view of the keys... either way it's a function call and not required for membership testing

Comment: @JonClements i learn way more by answering questions than i do by asking them

Answer (score 0):

A **list** is a sequence of elements.  Elements are numbered (and ordered) by an **implicit index**. It is this index what you mainly use to identify the elements within the list.  Elements can be repeated.  Indexes are not.  If you assign a new value to any element (identified by its **index**), the new value will replace the old one.

Example: In `["day", "midnight", "night", "noon", "day", "night"]`, (implicit) indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.  `list[0]` is "day", `list[1]` is "midnight", `list[4]` is also "day", and so on.  `list[3]= "midday"` changes the value of element 3 from "noon" to "midday".  `list.append("afternoon")` adds an element at the end of the list, which becomes `list[6]`.

Lists are useful to represent:

- Collections of (possibly repeated) elements.
- Collections of elements when their order (position in the list) is
  important.

A **dictionary** is a collection of elements with no intrinsic order.  Elements within the dictionary are identified by **explicit keys**.  As with lists, elements can be repeated, but keys can not, and if you assign a new value to any element (identified by its **key**), the new value will replace the old one.

Example: In `{"dia": "day", "medianoche": "midnight", "noche": "night", "mediodia": "noon", "tag": "day", "nacht": "night"}` keys are "dia", "medianoche", "noche", "mediodia", "tag", and "nacht".  `dict["dia"]` is "day", `dict["medianoche"]` is "midnight", `dict["tag"]` is also "day", and so on.  `dict["mediodia"]= "midday"` would replace the value of the element identified by "mediodia" from "noon" to "midday", and `dict["tardes"]= "afternoon"` would add an element for key "tardes" with value "afternoon", as there was no previous element identified by "tardes".  This is different to lists, which require `append` to add elements.

Dictionaries are useful to represent:

- Associations ("translations", "equivalencies") of data (i.e. of keys
  into elements, but not the other way round because elements can be duplicate).
- "Lists" with "indexes" that are not integer values (but strings, floating point values, etc)
- "Sparse lists", where keys are integers, but the vast mayority of
  elements is None.  This is usually done to save memory.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are creating an empty list

```
values = []
```

Then, you create a dictionary `{newvalue : oldvalue}` with only one element `oldvalue` whose key is `newvalue`.  And finally, you add this dictionary to the list through method `append`.  Yes, in Python it's absolutely valid to have dictionaries as elements of lists and lists as elements of dictionaries (or even their keys).  However, this is most probably not what you intended to achieve.

If what you want is a list with elements `newvalue` and `oldvalue`, you should have written:

```
values= []
values.append(newvalue)
values.append(oldvalue)
```

or simply

```
values= [newvalue, oldvalue]
```

If what you want is a dictionary with a single element `oldvalue` identified by key `newvalue`, you should have written:

```
values= {}
values[newvalue]= oldvalue
```

or simply

```
values= {newvalue: oldvalue}
```

Your code is not working because `values` is initially empty, so the `for` loop will not iterate at all.  What you probably intended is:

```
values= {}
if newvalue not in values.keys():    # "newvalue not in values" is shorter but can be misleading
    values[newvalue]= oldvalue
```

or

```
values= {}
if values[newvalue] is None:
    values[newvalue]= oldvalue
```

Additionally, `values.update({newvalue: oldvalue})` is a synonym to `values[newvalue]= oldvalue`, but you seem to be trying to use a mix of this form and lists by doing `values.append({newvalue: oldvalue})`.  Again, a dictionary is not a list of single-element dictionaries (which is what you were building and trying to manipulate).