# Store repetitive data in python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a small task with excel sheet and python and the problem that I'm facing is i have few lines of code to perform string manipulation on the data which i fetch from the sheet. Since i got plenty of sheets,sometimes only limited number of sheets are required and couple of time whole excel sheet to perform string manipulation i can't write the same code everywhere so i thought of performing the operation once and storing it like `oldvalue : newvalue` so that whenever i read oldvalue i don't have to do manipulation again just fetch the newvalue from there. Now i tried using dictionary which is the best way to do it but the problem with using it is my key and value can both be repetitive and i don't want to update my previous entry with it. As per my knowledge we can't achieve it using dictionary. So what I'm asking is whether we have some kind of different data type to store it? Or do we actually need one? Can you help me figure out a way to solve it without using any data type?

**EDIT :**

The point is I'm getting the data from excel sheet and performing string manipulation on it and sometimes the key and the value are getting repetitive and since i'm using dictionary, it's updating previous value which i don't want to.

Comment: So, you're wondering if you can add info to a dictionary without updating and just throwing out new ones that would overlap?

Comment: Can you post some code that you tried out?

Comment: Punctuation is a good thing.

Comment: Being concise also helps. We don't necessarily need the whole story. Just where you're having key issues + your code

Comment: If you format your question in paragraphs, it's a lot easier to read. I also removed your "Thanks" signature - we don't do that on SO.

Comment: @sihrc: I disagree. It's way to common that they don't explain what they are trying to do, so you can't really help them.

Comment: @LennartRegebro True, but i feel like this one is a bit much. at least separate story / issue?

Comment: My code is kind of lengthy one.....basically i'm using xlrd package to read from it and getting data row by row, checking if the data is off desired type if not then perform string manipulation and then use that new value to store and fetch other contents. Hope i tried explaining it clearly @lecodesportif

Comment: if dict.get(key,None) != None: pass else: save

Comment: No, you haven't. It seems to me that you want to cache the results of calculating a specific operation. But then you say you can't use a dictionary because keys have to be unique. And that makes no sense. If the key is the same, it's the same operation. Certainly that's the whole *point*?

Comment: @sihrc i don't want to delete i want to keep it like it is and not update previous value

Comment: ok just don't delete them. same concept

Comment: why not make each key:value pair an own dictionary and append it to a list

Comment: @lecodesportif if keys are unique, just don't ever update them. only assign new ones. no need to make a bunch of dictionaries

Comment: fetch the newvalue, use it, and... then don't do anything else?  Your problem makes no sense.

Comment: "it's updating previous value which i don't want to." - Well, so don't do that then.

Comment: @LennartRegebro - Isn't it the nature in the dcitionary to have only one key and one value to it?

Comment: Seems like this question continues [q18064362](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18064362/214178) from the same OP.

Comment: @NottyShinchan: Of course. You still have not explained why you want anything else. In fact, in your last question, your problem was that in a list, it *allowed* repetition. So now you use a dict, and suddenly that's a problem? You seem to not understand what you are saying or doing. I recommend a tutorial in basic Python programming.

Comment: @LennartRegebro i mentioned it that i will have to fetch the other data using them, while the manipulation and it's old value are same there data might be different so updating the value is like fetching the content of new one what about the previous one?

Comment: "The other data"? You aren't making any sense. Your sentence is near unreadable. Punctuation! Grammar!

Comment: Perhaps we'll be able to get somewhere if you post some of your raw data and what you want your data structure to look like before and after

Comment: from your edit, try including the cell name in the key itself to make every possible entry in the sheet create a unique entry without overwriting anything ever. You can then strip it off later if needed to get back the original value (so wrap it in something that will not appear in your data).

Answer (score 2):

This will check if your dictionary contains a value for a specified key. If not, you can manipulate your string and save it for that key. If it does, it will grab that value and use it as your manipulated string.

```
""" Stuff is done. New string to manipulated is found """
if key not in dict:
    value = ... #manipulated string
    dict[key] = value
else: 
    manipulated_string = dict[key] #did this before, have the value already
```

Comment: what will this do to help me. can you explain it please?

Comment: so we are updating the key with it's value again?

Comment: @NottyShinchan if you think this code updates the `dict` more than once, you need to seriously relearn what a `dict` does.

Comment: @roippi assuming he has once before

Comment: not working brother @sihrc...keeps getting error `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`

Comment: It would help if you could post your code and the error when you run it.